# jQuery show/hide a single div with same class as others

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently making a comment and like system just like the one on facebook. But I just can't figure out how to choose the specific div!

My current HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='activoptions'><a href='#'>Like</a>  <a href='#' class="addcomment">Add commentr</a>  <a href='#'>Share</a>
</div>
<ul class="addcommentbox">
    <li class="commentlist">
        <div class="CommentBox">
            <div class="CommentBoxPicBox">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="CommentBoxTextBox">
                <div class="CommentBoxTextBoxName">Name</div>
                <div class="CommentBoxTextBoxText">Some lovely text inside a lovely div</div>
                <div class="CommentBoxTextBoxTime">x minutes ago - <a href="#">Like</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have set the "CommentBox" CSS to `display:none;` so its invisible, and my jQuery: `$(".commentbox").show();`

It's just how the jQuery choose the right div that has been triggered a link not visible in the code above but its called ".commentadd". I have looked everywhere on jquery.net forum and I've found this little code snippet.

```
$(".addcomment").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var child = $this.find('.addcommentbox').html();
    $(child).show();
});
```

EDIT: Sorry it's so unprecise...  I will edit it at once and clarify it more for you..
Okay so.. I'm getting all recent activities and statuses and I'm giving all of them that HTML structure above. What I want is when someone clicks like, comment or share, then it's only the activity they clicked that gets queried through some ajax and inserted to the database.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise? I have no idea what you're trying to ask...

Comment: Ok and whats wrong with the code you found, could you please give us more of your code and detail what you want us to help you with

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".addcomment").click(function(){
    $('.CommentBox').show();
});
```

Should be enough. Try it out, and let me know if you run into new issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your HTML structure, I think you are trying to show the DIV without knowing an ID.

```
$(".addcomment").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.CommentBox').show();
});
```

Mind posting your HTML structure (including where `.addcomment` is) so that I can make the code work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add different "id"s on your "div"s and match the "id"s like this :

```
$("#my_id").show(); // or you can use "toggle" to show/hide
```

Details:

```
$(".addcomment").click(function(){
     $("#" + $(this).attr('id')).show(); // or toggle
});
```

I hope my answer is clear, I don't know...

Comment: i don't know if thats what im looking for. i have updated my post a little. but what im looking for is a way to- or a script for-, selecting the right .addcommentbox out of many. think of it as nearly identical to the system on facebook :)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript doesn't line up with your HTML as the classes are all different, but in the script you posted:

```
 $(".addcomment").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var child = $this.find('.addcommentbox').html();
    $(child).show();
 });
```

child is a text node, not a jQuery element list. Remove the .html() from the end and that will show the div with class "addcommentbox". On another note, you might want to add e.preventDefault(); to prevent the default action on the link click (as I have added above)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your html structure.  If you can wrap your whole "add comment" and "commentbox" section in wrapper, than you can select it without a problem.

See this [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dNEDf/)